# MySQL - Filtering results by other tables

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure that has a main purpose of locating 9 users closest to you based on a longitude and latitude coordinate. However, I need to filter these results `(and still return 9)` based on values of other tables.

Here is the procedure that I'm currently using that doesn't have any filtering.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE lat FLOAT(11,8);
    DECLARE lon FLOAT(11,8);
    DECLARE dist INT(11);

    SELECT latitude, longitude, search_radius 
    INTO lat, lon, dist 
    FROM accounts 
    INNER JOIN account_settings 
    ON accounts.account_id = account_settings.account_id 
    WHERE accounts.account_id = account_in;

    SELECT account_id, first_name, bio, birthdate
    , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(lat) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(lon) ) + sin( radians(lat) ) * sin(radians( latitude )) ) ) 
    AS distance 
    FROM `accounts` 
    WHERE account_id != account_in 
    HAVING distance < dist 
    ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 9;
END
```

However, I need to add some conditions to the select statement at the bottom, making it so it will still return 9 `(if available)` based on filtering from the following tables.

```
blocked_users
completed_test
failed_test
```

The three tables above have the same table structure of `[ account_id, other_id ]`.

How would I make sure that none of the users returned in the last select statement are present in the `other_id` field of any of the tables listed, while matched with the corresponding `account_id` passed through the `account_in` variable.

I've been racking my brain for about 6 hours and I just can't seem to come up with a good conclusion. This query is much higher level (or I'm overthinking it a lot) than I'm used to dealing with. As i only have basic MySQL knowledge.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` these tables and use `WHERE othertable.account_id IS NULL` for all three of them (using `AND`)

Comment: You've not said how to apply the filtering - if you want to exclude entries in a table the do a left join and require the key of the exclusion table to be null. For inclusion, just do an inner join. And learn how to use the geospatial indexing in mysql.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't see how that would work, as `other table.account_id IS NULL` will never be true, but in fact I need to find out what `other table.other_id` is where `other table.account_id` is = `account_in`. 

I feel like it's a little more complicated.

Comment: You asked how to ensure that ***none** of the users returned in the last select statement are present in the `other_id` field of any of the tables listed*. I suggested to remove these users upfront by using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on these tables and then filtering only not matched records.